# ipcRenderer instead of remote

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ipc

So apparently it's a bad practice to use the `remote` module in Electron and they are planning to kill it. They say the `ipcRenderer` module should be used instead.

But the ipc thing is a event system.

What if within the preload script I need to get a certain variable from the main process? I cannot listen for the ipc event that gives me that variable because it may come after the script has finished!
With the remote module when you call the `remote.app.function()` that gets you what you want the script is blocked until you get the result, just like with any normal function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remote` is nothing more than a wrapper to ipc. If you can do something in remote, it should be available via ipcRenderer as well.

What you're looking for is `sendSync` https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendsyncchannel-args allows to wait ipc returns message back. But as noted in `remote`'s deprecation reasoning, this is possible footgun in general and should be used carefully.